# Angular Pipe and TypeScript Type Guard

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I read about type guards in typescript [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). But I still get compiler errors.

> Error:(21, 14) TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a
>   call signature. Type '{ (callbackfn: (value: Foo,
>   index: number, array: Foo...' has no compatible call signatures.

I got following classes:

**Foo.ts**

```
export class Foo {
  expired: boolean;
}
```

**Bar.ts**

```
export class Bar {
  foo: Foo;
}
```

**MyPipe.ts**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myPipe'
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: Foo[] | Bar[], isExpired: Boolean): Foo[] | Bar[] {
    if (!items) {
      return items;
    }

    if (items[0] instanceof Foo) {
      return items.filter((foo: Foo) => {
        return foo.expired == isExpired;
      });
    } else {
      return items.filter((bar: Bar) => {
        return bar.foo.expired == isExpired;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**The question is, how can I achieve the use of union binding for my parameter "items" and the type guard usage at the same time in my angular pipe using typescript?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript will generally not narrow the type of a variable based on the type of a field (with the exception of discriminated unions). More specifically typescript will do no narrowing based on array indexing (this is a known limitation)

The simplest thing you can do is use a type assertion, or the more elegant solution, a custom type guard:

```
class Foo { private x: string; expired: boolean }
class Bar { private x: string; foo: Foo }

function isArrayOf<T>(ctor: new (...args: any[]) => T, arr: any): arr is T[] {
    return arr[0] instanceof ctor
}

export class MyPipe {
    transform(items: Foo[] | Bar[], isExpired: Boolean): Foo[] | Bar[] {
        if (!items) {
            return items;
        }

        if (isArrayOf(Foo, items) {
            return items.filter((foo: Foo) => {
                return foo.expired == isExpired;
            });
        } else {
            return items.filter((bar: Bar) => {
                return bar.foo.expired == isExpired;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20class%20Foo%20%7B%20private%20x%3A%20string%3B%20expired%3A%20boolean%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Bar%20%7B%20private%20x%3A%20string%3B%20foo%3A%20Foo%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20isArrayOf%3CT%3E(ctor%3A%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%2C%20arr%3A%20any)%3A%20arr%20is%20T%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20arr%5B0%5D%20instanceof%20ctor%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20MyPipe%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20transform(items%3A%20Foo%5B%5D%20%7C%20Bar%5B%5D%2C%20isExpired%3A%20Boolean)%3A%20Foo%5B%5D%20%7C%20Bar%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!items)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20items%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(isArrayOf(Foo%2C%20items)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20items.filter((foo%3A%20Foo)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20foo.expired%20%3D%3D%20isExpired%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20items.filter((bar%3A%20Bar)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20bar.foo.expired%20%3D%3D%20isExpired%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A)